# MYSQL - Why value is null on this case

Tags: mysql, owncloud

i write a trigger and the value returned by the select queries is null and i don't understand why . `Oc_storages` is an table provied by Owncloud , there are two fields `id` in `varchar` and `numeric_id` in `int` . The trigger is on when i do a delete on the table `oc_filecache`. Parent is a `oc_filecache's` field , the type is INT . With a signal , i see that `old.parent` is not null.

EDIT 16/05 2:01 PM : The problem is on the commande set because i set a string like 'user' and the value is null

EDIT 16/05 2:10 PM: Code updated. I say that when i set the value at 130 , the value of proprio is null

EDIT 19/05 16:06 : SOLVED . I write "set proprio =  " and the value is not null now. Tks all

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_apres_delete_filecache 
AFTER DELETE ON oc_filecache FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    declare proprio varchar(255);

    set @proprio = ( select distinct id from oc_storages where numeric_id = OLD.parent );

    INSERT INTO histo_filecache
    (action, date_action, path,who)
    VALUES
    ('delete', NOW(), OLD.path,proprio);
END
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that "select distinct id from oc_storages where numeric_id = OLD.parent" is returning some value?

Comment: What type of trigger is it and which table is it assigned to? Edit your question and add the part where you define the trigger.

Comment: I updated my question . When i write set @proprio = 13 ;  The value of proprio is null

Comment: Looks like it should be a _BEFORE DELETE_ trigger.

Comment: Thanks Sloan for your answer but that not explain why the value of proprio is null whatever i write.

Comment: @SloanThrasher any idea?

Comment: Is the type of id in oc_storages a varchar(255) or int? @proprio should have the same type as oc_storages.id.

Comment: Also, is there any chance that the query after the set @proprio can return multiple rows? I ask because of the _distinct_ in the query. It should be unnecessary if the numeric_id is unique.

Comment: @SloanTrasher I said  : when i set the value of proprio at 130 , the result is the same . The value of proprio is Null . oc_storages.id is varchar(255) .

Comment: Please add an answer yourself and mark it as accepted